# Load massive HTML data via Ajax-Request

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, browser

i have a problem and can not find a solution at this moment... i am calling an ajax request to fetch html data from my backend system. the backend system renders a html table with 8000 rows and many information in the table cells. php needs 1 second to fetch and render the data, the browser needs 40 seconds to display the data....

the ajax call is build with the jquery.post() method and the response is html. i insert the responded html with javascripts innerHtml function because jquery are slower than this native function...

do someone have an idea, how i could speed up that process? i thought about splitting the response into chunks and display it with timeouts, but that did not work^^

thx!

edit: i cant do a infinite scroll scenario. the table contents are parsed into a treetable class and have hierarchys. it has to work that i could collapse and expand all levels with one click. load just what i see is a problem to i think with this scenario.

Comment: Don't use timeouts, use callbacks :)

Comment: how do you mean this^^ i use a callback at the ajax post request of course. then i started a timed out callback to push chunks of the big html response into the dom. that works, but it was slow and the user can see that something is inserted, but the browser is still frozen and the process needs longer than just wait to insert everything at once to the dom^^

Comment: Is anyone looking at 8000 rows of data at one time? No, they are not. Fetch as many as you need to fill the display, then fetch more as needed.

Comment: Infinite scroll! As @dadooGames says, no one is looking at 8000 at once.

Comment: i thought about this, but the table has a hierarchy^^ it is needed to collapse and expand some contents. in many of the times i have only 5 top level rows to display but level 2 has 4000 lines. i am not sure how to load this with infinite scroll...

Comment: Might be faster to send json data and build the HTML in the javascript (especially considering that table markup is always rather bloated). In any case, you should reduce it to what's necessary. 8000 rows is way too much to expect a snappy page.

Comment: Agree with @WesleyMurch on that.   JSON data would be much smaller in size to transmit...  Javascript can then parse the JSON and put it in a table form.

Comment: why should that be faster? the complete request with response are just 1 second. after i put the response into the innerHtml it needs 40 seconds to display it... is it really faster if i will create the table rows first and then insert line by line with javascript dynamically? i could not imagine this :(

Comment: In response to your edit: you certainly *can* make an ajax request for more rows (start with the top level, fetch the sub-level stuff via ajax). It seems obvious to me. For further clarification, please add your current code.